# Ibm http server revealing the ip address in load balancing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver, worklight-console

I have set up the IBM Worklight in an IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile farm as follows[image]

Everything works fine, but the problem is while deploying the .war file of protected console

1. After configuration, While accessing the IBM HTTP Server(IHSnode/worklight/console) it shows the authentication page

[image]

2. After providing the valid credentials, it shows the authenticated worklight console page but it reveals the IP address of the Worklight Server(liberty server)

[image]

In this case, I want to know whether the Worklight server[Worklight node] IP Address is revealed or Worklight server responds to the client[IHS redirects the URL to Worklight server].

Any help in this...

Comment: The IP is of the Worklight server or the IBM HTTP server?

Comment: As far as my understanding it reveals the Worklight server IP.

Comment: @ravidor,dhineshsundar-It is the ip address of the worklight server

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the "Host" element in Server.xml of Liberty Profile Server. 
The DNS host name, used by a client to request a resource. Use '*' for all available network interfaces. By default, its value is "localhost". That's why in client it shows the IP address assigned to that. Please give a try.

Comment: There is no host element in server.xml. I think you are talking about <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" >

Comment: @sureshRamasubbu, can you please share the log of the IBM HTTP Server while the IP getting displayed.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jun/2014:17:07:37 +0530] "GET /worklight/console HTTP/1.1" 200 5983
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jun/2014:17:07:44 +0530] "POST /worklight/j_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 -

Answer (score 0):

Apart from changing the server.xml as PV R suggested below,

In the worklight.properties, change the value of `publicWorklightHostname` to the URL of the worklight server and while building the application for remote server, put in the hostname of the server not IP Address